# redirect back to listing page from its single page

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi i am new to WordPress Development. I have created a custom post type of "projects", where projects list are shown. i want to put a button "Back to Projects" in its single page (single-project.php), that will redirect back to its listing page. How can i do that? look at the last line in code. please help.

```
 if ($query->have_posts() ):
        while ($query->have_posts() ):
            $query->the_post();
                                    ?>

                                    <div class="related-project-single">
                                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('image_size_720_680'); ?>
                                        <div class="wrapper-button">
                                            <a class="bp-button bp-button-plain button-yellow btn-slider" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo esc_html__('view project','inspiry') ?> <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="wrapper-location">
                                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                            <?php
                                            $feature_location_related = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'bp-location',true);
                                            if(!empty($feature_location_related)){
                                                ?>
                                                <p class="featured-location"><?php echo esc_html($feature_location_related);?></p>
                                                <?php
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php
                                endwhile;endif;?>
                            <a href="">Back to projects</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you've tried something link this?

```
<a href="index.php?post_type=projects">Back to projects</a>
```

Comment: unless his list is paged, then it would go to the first one everytime. 
If it is paged he can save the page number in a session, and create a variable from that, So something like this href="index.php/projects/<?php echo $pageNumber ?>" (depending on the link structure)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work

```
  <a href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link('projects'); ?>">Back to projects</a>
```